# How to Troubleshoot CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML / CSS project on JS Fiddle with several issues [jsfiddle ZyBZT](http://jsfiddle.net/jp2code/ZyBZT/).

- The `<DIV class"footer">` is not showing up at the bottom.
- The background image does not display: `url('http://i.imgur.com/z5vCh.png')`
- The Sprite Images are not showing up in the `<UL>` list.

Originally, the Sprites were working, and nothing I had added has changed any of the Sprite CSS code, which is as follows:

```
#nav {
  list-style-type:none; /* removes the bullet from the list */
  margin:20 auto;
  text-shadow:4px 4px 8px #696969; /* creates a drop shadow on text in non-IE browsers */
  white-space:nowrap; /* ensures text stays on one line */
  width:600px; /* Allows links to take up proper height */
}
#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 192px;    
}
#nav a {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Sp7jc.gif') 0 -100px no-repeat;
  display: block;
  height: 50px; /* This allowed the buttons to be full height */
  color: Blue;
}
#nav a:hover {
  background-position: 0 -50px;
  color:Red;
}
#nav .active, a:hover {
  background-position: 0 0;        
  color: Black;
}
#nav .active:hover {
  background-position: 0 0;        
  color: Black;
}
#nav span {
  position:relative;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle; /* This doesn't seem to work (???) */
}
​
```

Sometimes, the background image works, but other times it does not.

Lately, I have been trying to get this FOOTER div to work, and now it appears that much more of it is messed up.

How am I supposed to be able to tell when one piece of CSS breaks another piece of CSS? How do I tell when something tries to execute the CSS and there is an error?

Comment: Google Chrome (along with other browsers have a developers tool) right click inspect element is really helpful you can dynamically change CSS and HTML.

Comment: You can't use imgur to host your images, they'll send back a 403. Even *if* that worked, imgur is not nearly reliable enough to serve up your UI elements.

Comment: Nate, when I use Chrome, it has a line struck through my `background:` element. Why? What does that mean?

Comment: Mike, I only use Imgur when posting here. Our project is for an internal intranet, so it has no links accessible via the outside world. Is there a more appropriate spot to post? I use Imgur because that is where SO sends images whenever pics are uploaded.

Comment: With regards to the line being struck through the background: this means that there is another CSS style that has overwritten your style, probably due to having higher selector specificity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can to is to

1. Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or the browser developer tools of your choice to see what classes/styles the browser is applying, and the effects, and
2. Study the HTML standards to make sure you're coding them correctly; keep in mind that they are often counter-intuitive.  MDN has some excellent articles on [HTML layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Layout_System_Overview), [vertical alignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/vertical-align) and many other HTML/CSS/Javascript topics.

Comment: +1. Currently, I develop with Chrome and IE. Every time I try to download a version of Firefox, the installers want to attach all this bloat ware that I don't trust, so I cancel the install.

Comment: @jp2code Bloatware? Are you downloading the installer from the official site? I can't recall any bloatware there but you can always use one of the optimized FF builds like Pale Moon or Waterfox instead.

Comment: **Ugh!** Even Waterfox is trying to install AVG Security Toolbar. What's with all these companies trying to throw spam on you with their installers lately? I'm pretty sure the AVG Security Toolbar is free, so if I wanted it, I'd go and get it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the footer problem easy enough:

```
div.footer {
  bottom:0px;
  position:fixed;
  text-align:center;
}
```

However, this does NOT answer the main question: **How to Troubleshoot**!

Comment: If anything is going wrong, you should always remove CSS/HTML/Javascript instead of adding. You can do this 'live' by using the Web Inspector on Chrome. Right Click and select 'Inspect Element'. It will show you how your HTML/CSS is structured and you can delete nodes and change CSS. Try deleting everything that is not connected to the problem (e.g HTML code, Javascript that doesn't apply to this bit of the project etc). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Best tool I've found for this is Firebug, it's still better than Chrome's tools.  When you inspect an element it will show you the hierarchy of applied styles and those styles that have been overridden. (with strikethrough)

This is your best tool to see what is happening.

I think you're having z-index issues and the text-shadow is causing issues.
Removed the `z-index:-1` and the `text-shadow` and the background behaves.